# When does finite presentability of the associated graded Lie algebra of a group imply the group is finitely presented?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group; let $L(G)$ denote the graded Lie algebra (over $\mathbb{Q}$) associated to the lower central series of $G$. I would like to know conditions for when the finite presentability of $L(G)$ implies $G$ is finitely presented.

Comment: It looks like a hopeless approach to prove finite presentability of the Torelli group? there are no general results of this kind, and in small classes where it holds, finite presentability has to be checked anyway.

Comment: For pro-p groups it is true: if $L(G)$ is finitely presented, then $G$ is finitely presented. But $L(G)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-Lie algebra.

Comment: @Dietrich: this is really distinct since $G$ is discrete in the question, and for pro-$p$-groups $L(G)$ is defined from the $p$-series of $G$. Here $L(G)$ only reflects torsion-free nilpotent quotients of $G$.

Comment: Yves, does finite presentability of the Torelli group imply finite presentability of the the group? I am interested in even small classes where the result holds. Would you describe these classes. Thanks.